# Listview did not receive notification

Tags: android

I am getting this error in one of my `ListView.`  The thing is I am calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` but still I am getting this error. could any one guide me what I am doing wrong.

getting exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

The content of the adapter has changed but `ListView` did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` when its content changes.

```
[in ListView(2131034328, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.activities.RestaurentListActivity$CustomAdapterRestaurant)]
```

Comment: Did you honor this line? `Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.`

Comment: The logcat is self-explanatory ; you're either changing the adapter from another thread or you're calling notifyDataSetChanged from a wrong line, where no change in data has happened

Comment: Provide me the lines where you are getting error, so then we can help you